# stl::find_if with user search

Tags: c++, stl

I was wondering if there was a way to use the stl::find_if to search for a user inputted value

I don't know to do that without using any bad conventions(globals) or adding loads of extended code.

For example, if a user inputs a int x for 10, then I want to search an vector of ints

```
iterator = find_if(begin,end,pred) //but how does pred know the user inputted value?
```

Comment: No a function object is fine, as long as it's not dozens of lines of code

Comment: I think in this particular case you just choose the correct algorithm: `find(begin, end, user_input);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `pred` must be an instance of a type that has the overloaded () operator, so it can be called like a function.

```
struct MyPred
{
    int x;

    bool operator()(int i)
    {
        return (i == x);
    }
};
```

(Using a `struct` for brevity here)

```
std::vector<int> v;

// fill v with ints

MyPred pred;
pred.x = 5;

std::vector<int>::iterator f 
     = std::find_if(v.begin(), 
                    v.end(), 
                    pred);
```

Writing custom classes like this (with "loads" of code!) is cumbersome to say the least, but will be improved a lot in C++0x when lambda syntax is added.

Comment: The programmer sets 'x' by assigning to it, as shown above. Are you asking about how to read input from the user? That's basically a totally different question.

Comment: No problem - obviously it's better practice to make the data members private and provide a constructor to initialize them, I just made `x` public to make it shorter and hopefully clearer.

Comment: Using a ctor actually makes the code shorter:
`...std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), pred(5));`
Of course UncleBen's comment had the right answer -- when you just need to find a particular value, use std::find instead of find_if.

Comment: Instead of assigning the value to x later, you should just set it in the constructor:
`struct MyPred {
   MyPred(int v) : x(v) {}
   /* ... */
}
`

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`equal_to`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/equal_to.html):

```
find_if(a.begin(), a.end(), bind2nd(equal_to<int>(), your_value));
```

Comment: Ah.. bind2nd.. I love functional programming in C++ ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use boost::bind, for more general solution, for example:

```
struct Point
{
 int x;
 int y;
};


vector< Point > items;

find_if( items.begin(), items.end(), boost::bind( &Point::x, _1 ) == xValue );
```

will find a point whose x equals xValue